# what is the meaning of filter2([1;0;-1],temp) in finding gradient of an image?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the gradient of image using the following code.

```
function [Fx,Fy]=myGradient(I)
%correctig gradient on edges
I=imadjust(I);
[hcol,hrow]=size(I);
temp= ones(hcol+2,hrow+2);
temp(2:1+hcol,2:1+hrow)=I(:,:);

Fx=filter2([1;0;-1],temp);
Fx=Fx(3:hcol,3:hrow);
Fy=filter2([1;0;-1]',temp);
Fy=Fy(3:hcol,3:hrow);
```

Can you please tell me the meaning of the code: 
    filter2([1;0;-1],temp)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same as a 2D convolution of the image `temp` with the *kernal* `[1;0;-1]`. This will find the gradient across the rows of the image. Convolution will slide the kernal over the image and for each pixel. It places the center of the kernal over the pixel of interest and then does an elementwise multiplication of the kernal with the image where they overlap. For your kernal this will be the pixel you are calculating the gradient for, the pixel directly above it and the pixel directly below it. The center of the kernal is zero so the pixel of interest has no effect, and what happens is you basically are subtracting the pixel below from the pixel above. You do this for each pixel. So this is the difference between the two neighbours of your pixel and hence the gradient.

Comment: Good explanation. I think that `filter2` implement correlation, not convolution. For this case, it doesn't matter...